# Navgation Freezes in Framework7 v1 App

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

I have single view Framework7 v1 app with href toolbar buttons and panel overlay links to seven different HTML pages within the app. I can navigate back and forth for a bit, but after a certain point, I can’t click the back button, and none of the toolbar links or the overlay menu. I’m stuck on whatever page. I’ve tried setting domCache to true and false in the JS and it’s not making a difference. I've also tried adding this to my href links:

```html
data-reload="true" data-ignore-cache="true"
```

Aside from this, the app is working and ready to distribute.

Comment: if possible can u make fiddle in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was a widget DOM ID conflict. Two map widgets had the same ID so the app just froze. It's working now.